# Got Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getContext' of undefined or null when try to clear a canvas

Tags: javascript, html

Okay, I read most of the error of this type, and well, all of them doesn't work. It is very annoying, and I will just spam to get past that more code than word limit because I already figure out why but need to include this for people with the same people as me. Look in the Answers to see my solution and why. sad s dasda hujs agdu saudgs adhy usuhd c asuyhdg uhafash ugduy gsjd sad hijo joilh iughiu gtyb sd oini ouiah osuhhodi oshuas daeygtsy dhuois dha

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

  <head>
    
    <meta charset="UTF-8">

    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=NO, width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <script src="/Tests/Map Test 2/Map3.js"></script>

  </head>

  <body>
    
    <canvas id="myCanvas" width="400" height="400" style="border:1px solid red"></canvas>

  </body>

</html>
```

Javascript

```
c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");

function clearCanvas(c) {
    var ctx = c.getContext('2d');   // gets reference to canvas context
    ctx.beginPath();    // clear existing drawing paths
    ctx.save(); // store the current transformation matrix
    
    // Use the identity matrix while clearing the canvas
    ctx.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);
    ctx.fillStyle = "red";
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 300, 150);
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, c.width, c.height);

    ctx.restore();  // restore the transform
};

clearCanvas(c);
```

Most humorous is that if I paste the same javascript code inside the script block of HTML, then it work fine...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

  <head>
    
    <meta charset="UTF-8">

    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=NO, width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

  </head>

  <body>
    
    <canvas id="myCanvas" width="400" height="400" style="border:1px solid red"></canvas>

    <script>
    c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");

    function clearCanvas(c) {
        var ctx = c.getContext('2d');   // gets reference to canvas context
        ctx.beginPath();    // clear existing drawing paths
        ctx.save(); // store the current transformation matrix
        
        // Use the identity matrix while clearing the canvas
        ctx.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);
        ctx.fillStyle = "red";
        ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 300, 150);
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, c.width, c.height);

        ctx.restore();  // restore the transform
    };

    clearCanvas(c);
    </script>

  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Huh, funny enough, this exact same duplicate question was how I was able to answer this question before I post it. Now I just got to figure out how to redraw canvas because despite at the moment it was clean and no longer pass the original function, it will still draw same thing rather than draw new one despite the original one is now locked and inaccessible because it no longer pass the function as true even if it now pass new function as true it wont use it...

Comment: Well, if a question already exists and has an accepted answer that solves the problem, there's really no need to post it again. My point was that you should feel free to remove the question, since it already exists.

Comment: I merely thought it is a good idea to keep it here as that question was answered in 2012, so I thought to keep it here so people know it still works in 2020. but just say the word again and I will remove this post.

Comment: If a duplicate is outdated, you can update the accepted answer; some of the biggest questions have answers that received several updates over the years. In the end stackoverflow is supposed to be an exhaustive FAQ, that's what I use as guideline when it comes to answering/commenting/flagging. The question is already marked as dupe, so it's up to you whether you want to remove it.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, you need to put Jquery script after canvas, because apparently if the script is read first before the canvas, then it cant find canvas, then it will cause a null error... Just leaving this here for people to figure out their error.

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

  <head>
    
    <meta charset="UTF-8">

    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=NO, width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <canvas id="myCanvas" width="400" height="400" style="border:1px solid red"></canvas>

    <script src="/Tests/Map Test 2/Map3.js"></script>

  </head>

  <body>

  </body>

</html>
```

Javascript

```
c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");

function clearCanvas(c) {
    var ctx = c.getContext('2d');   // gets reference to canvas context
    ctx.beginPath();    // clear existing drawing paths
    ctx.save(); // store the current transformation matrix
    
    // Use the identity matrix while clearing the canvas
    ctx.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);
    ctx.fillStyle = "red";
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 300, 150);
    ctx.clearRect(100, 100, c.width, c.height);

    ctx.restore();  // restore the transform
};

clearCanvas(c);
```